# Iterating XML nodes

Tags: c#, xml

I am iterating over an XML Node List which contains Gnomes (/GnomeArmy/Gnome), while I am iterating I would like to iterate through the list of children that belong to the gnome.

Currently I have it picking the first Gnome's children for both gnomes, this is incorrect as they both have there own children.

i.e. Gnome1 Children are Jessica & Nick, Gnome2 Children are also Jessica & Nick (this is wrong).

Thanks.

Code:

```
public static List<Gnome> ReadGnomes(string file)
{
    List<Gnome> gnomeList = new List<Gnome>();

    XmlDocument gnomeFile = new XmlDocument();
    gnomeFile.Load(file);

    // Get list of Gnomes
    XmlNodeList nodes = gnomeFile.SelectNodes(string.Format("/GnomeArmy/Gnome"));

    Gnome gnome = null;
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        gnome = new Gnome();

        // General Attributes
        gnome.Name = node["Name"].InnerText;
        gnome.Colour = node["Colour"].InnerText;

        XmlNodeList children = node.SelectSingleNode("/GnomeArmy/Gnome/Children").ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlNode child in children)
        {
            if (child.Name == "Child")
            {
                gnome.Children = gnome.Children + " " + child.InnerText;
            }
        }
        gnomeList.Add(gnome);
    }
    return gnomeList;
}
```

XML:

```
<GnomeArmy>

    <Gnome>
        <Name>Harry</Name>
        <Colour>Blue</Colour>
        <Children>
            <Child>Jessica</Child>
            <Child>Nick</Child>
        </Children>
    </Gnome>

    <Gnome>
        <Name>Mathew</Name>
        <Colour>Red</Colour>
        <Children>
            <Child>Lisa</Child>
            <Child>James</Child>
        </Children>
    </Gnome>

</GnomeArmy>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

```
List<Gnome> gnomes = XDocument.Load("path")
                     .Descendants("Gnome")
                     .Select(g => new Gnome {
                       Name = (string)g.Element("Name"),
                       Colour = (string)g.Element("Colour"),   
                       Childrens = g.Element("Children")
                          .Elements("Child")
                          .Select(x => new Children { Name = (string)x)).ToList());
```

I store `Childrens` into a `List`, you can change it,if you want just concatenate children names, you can use `string.Join` for that:

```
Childrens = string.Join(" ",g.Element("Children")
           .Elements("Child")
           .Select(x => (string)x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq to handle the nodes and children (sub) nodes accordingly via their `Descendants`

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
    <GnomeArmy>
       <Gnome><Name>Harry</Name><Colour>Blue</Colour>
            <Children><Child>Jessica</Child><Child>Nick</Child></Children>
       </Gnome>
       <Gnome><Name>Mathew</Name><Colour>Red</Colour>
            <Children><Child>Lisa</Child><Child>James</Child></Children>
        </Gnome>
    </GnomeArmy>");


Console.WriteLine (
xdoc.Descendants("Gnome")
    .Select (parent => string.Format("{0} has these kids {1}", 
                                     parent.Descendants("Name").First().Value,
                                     string.Join(", ", parent.Descendants("Child")
                                                             .Select (child => child.Value))
                                    )
             ));
```

Results from WriteLine

```
Harry has these kids Jessica, Nick
Mathew has these kids Lisa, James
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
XmlNodeList children = node.SelectSingleNode("/GnomeArmy/Gnome/Children").ChildNodes;
```

You are selecting the same node over and over.

[SelectSingleNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this was the problem as stated by @JonPall:

```
XmlNodeList children = node.SelectSingleNode("/GnomeArmy/Gnome/Children").ChildNodes;
```

The part of that statement which was causing the problem was "/GnomeArmy/", the / resulted in the SelectSingleNode going to the top of the XML Doc, remove the "/GnomeArmy" and "/" and it works :)

```
XmlNodeList children = node.SelectSingleNode("Gnome/Children").ChildNodes;
```

Credit to my lecturer and to @JonPall for highlighting the line of code.